# Help with a problem about Artinian rings from Christian Peskine's book

Tags: ring-theory, commutative-algebra, noetherian

I am stuck with problem 3, chapter 4, from the book of Peskine, *An Algebraic Introduction to Complex Projective Geometry*.

> Let $A$ be a Noetherian ring. Assume that if $a \in A$ is neither invertible nor nilpotent, then there exist $b \in A$ such that $b$ is not nilpotent and that $ab = 0$. Show that $A$ is Artinian.

I have tried to prove that every prime is also maximal since I already have the Noetherian property and I can't see how to prove directly the dcc.

Comment: Hmm, perhaps try constructing a DC of ideals, and use the fact that they're all finitely generated to get the contradiction?

Answer (score 5):

Here's a high-level proof - perhaps someone else will find a more elementary one.
$\DeclareMathOperator{\nil}{nil}$
$\DeclareMathOperator{\Ass}{Ass}$
$\DeclareMathOperator{\Spec}{Spec}$
$\DeclareMathOperator{\Min}{Min}$

Set $B := A/\nil(A)$. The assumption on $A$ implies that every nonunit in $B$ is a zerodivisor (notice: this is stronger than saying that every nonunit in $A$ is a zerodivisor). Thus every prime ideal $\mathfrak p$ of $B$ is contained in the union of the associated primes of $B$. But $B$ is reduced, so [every associated prime is minimal](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/658906/115654). Then $\displaystyle \mathfrak p \subseteq \bigcup_{\mathfrak q \in \Min(B)} \mathfrak q \implies \mathfrak p \subseteq \mathfrak q$ for some $\mathfrak q \in \Min(B) \implies \mathfrak p = \mathfrak q$. Thus every prime ideal of $B$ is minimal, so $\dim B = 0$, and so $\dim A = 0$.

Comment: The key point in an explicit form: If $A$ is a noetherian reduced ring, and every non-zero divisor is invertible, then $A$ is artinian.

Comment: I briefly had hopes for an elementary proof: If there is a nonmaximal prime $P$, you have a nonunit, nonnilpotent $a\in R\setminus P$. The $b$ that you are given must then be in $P$, and it has its own nonmaximal prime $Q$ that it isn't in, but $a\in Q$. I didn't see the way to a contradiction, though :) This is an accessible proof though! +1

Answer (score 5):

Here is my answer. Assume that $A$ is not artinian. Then there exists a maximal ideal not contained in the union of all minimal primes. Hence
there exists an element $a$ not invertible and not contained in any minimal prime.

Consequently if $ab=0$ then $b$ is contained in all minimal primes and is therefore nilpotent, contradicting the hypothesis.

Comment: Downvoted? Why?

Comment: (I have nothing to do with the downvote but) maybe the user found part of the reasoning too challenging. Hardest gap for me to fill in was the first "then", but maybe it's more obvious in the context of the book. It took three different theorems combined, but I guess they are all standard commutative algebra.

Comment: How do we see the first then?