# $\operatorname{Supp} f$ not Irreducible Component

Tags: algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra

Let $A$ be an integral domain and $a$ an embedded point. So it is given by a non-unit $f$. Let consider the support $\operatorname{Supp}  f$ (defined via $\operatorname{Supp}  f = \{p \in SpecA | f_p \neq 0 $ in $A_p \}$).

My question refers to a conclusion here: [If $A$ is reduced, Spec $A$ has no embedded points](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/658589/if-a-is-reduced-spec-a-has-no-embedded-points)

Why $\operatorname{Supp} f\not \supset V(f)$ imply that $\operatorname{Supp} f$ can't be an irreducible component?

Comment: If $A$ is integral there is only one irreducible component. Since $V(f)$ is not empty this says the support is not the whole space.